# NDSolve with minimum value

Tags: differential-equations

I want to plot the decay of $O_3$ to $O_2$.

My system and my code (x = $O_3$, y = $O_2$):

```
ϵ=98;
k=3;
ozonProb = {x'[t]==-x[t]-x[t]*y[t]+ϵ*k*y[t], 
            y'[t]==x[t]*((1-y[t])/ϵ)-k*y[t],
            x[0]==1,
            y[0]==0}
loes = NDSolve[ozonProb, {x, y}, {t, 0, 240}]
```

Now when I plot my $O_3$ or $O_2$ concentration:

```
Plot[x[t]/.loes, {t, 0, 2922}]
```

both of them reach a negative value after ~2 years. Is there a problem in my system?

Comment: Your Plot extends outside the domain of the NDSolve solution requested, i.e.,  `{t, 0, 240}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ϵ = 98;
k = 3;
ozonProb = {x'[t] == -x[t] - x[t]*y[t] + ϵ*k*y[t], 
   y'[t] == x[t]*((1 - y[t])/ϵ) - k*y[t], x[0] == 1, 
   y[0] == 0};
loes = NDSolve[ozonProb, {x, y}, {t, 0, 2922}];

Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], 100 y[t]} /. loes], {t, 0, 2922}]
```

[image]

Explanation

You solved your system in the range 0 .. 240 but your plot is in the range 0 .. 2922 . You got extrapolation difficulties.

Addendum to your question

```
loes2 = NDSolve[ozonProb, {x, y}, {t, 0, 3}];

Show[
 Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], 100 y[t]} /. loes2], {t, 0, 3}],
 Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], 100 y[t]} /. loes], {t, 0, 3}]
]
```

[image]

It is sufficient to solve the system in the range 0 ..2922 once.

Comment: No explanation?

Comment: Rewi, please comment on the changes you made in the OP's code that fixed the original problem (e.g. You extended the domain over which `NDSolve` operated, etc).

Comment: thank you :) If I want to use loes for i.e. {t,0,3} and {t,0,2922}, would it be better to define a Block for loes/use NDSolve twice (to get better WorkingPrecision i.e.?) or is it ok, if I use NDSolve with 2922 (the maximum time value) and plot in a range from 0 to 3 too?

Comment: @MarcoB Sorry, I thought that the code is easy to understand.

Comment: When you see the error, it's easy to understand.  When you don't see the error, it's not; and a simple explanation in this case makes it obvious and easy for others. (+1) --  Side note: The old `Plot` use to let warnings about extrapolation escape, which would probably have solved it for the OP before posting.

Comment: @Merlin see my addendum to your question